# Google app engine consistency parent/child member

Tags: google-app-engine, consistency

In the documentation, there's plenty of information about the 'eventual' consistency. However, I was wondering what the consistency with parent/child values is. Small example

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    ...
    String parentName;
    Child child = new Child(parentName);
}

@Entity
class Child {
    ...
    String parentName;

    Child(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }
}
```

If I were to update the field 'parentName' in the Parent, is it possible to have it updated in the Child as well?

Answer (score 1):

If by parent/child you mean these two entities are created in the same entity group, then yes you can update both entities in a single transaction, and the update will be atomic and strongly consistent.  (This entity group relationship is not fully specified in your code sample: you have to create the entities with appropriate keys.)